# using convereter in a setter of style wpf

Tags: wpf

I have a converter to convert `Double.Nan` to `null`.
I need to refer this in resourcedictionary.
I will include my code here

```
  <Style x:Key="LabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}" >
  <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Binding Path="Content" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}">
                    <Binding.Converter>
                        <local:NanToNullConverter/>
                    </Binding.Converter>
                </Binding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

This convereter is triggered. But value is not updating in the UI.
Binding is done like this

```
<Label Style="{DynamicResource LabelStyle}" Content="{Binding Filters_TanksModelObject.RunDown_HeaderPressureDischargeStart ,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ContentStringFormat="#.##" ></Label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Local properties are preferred over style properties, so your `<Setter Property="Content">` is ignored and only the `Content="{Binding Filters_TanksModelObject.RunDown_HeaderPressureDischargeStart ,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"` is used.

Instead, use

```
<Style x:Key="LabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}" >
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Binding Path="Filters_TanksModelObject.RunDown_HeaderPressureDischargeStart" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding.Converter>
                    <local:NanToNullConverter/>
                </Binding.Converter>
            </Binding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and remove the direct assignment. Or use this binding directly and don't rely on the style.

Comment: @user1665130  this is a nice solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

1 Add your converter as static resource

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:NanToNullConverter x:Key="nanToNullCnvrt"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

2 Add converter directly to Content property

```
<Label Style="{DynamicResource LabelStyle}" Content="{Binding Filters_TanksModelObject.RunDown_HeaderPressureDischargeStart, Converter={StaticResource nanToNullCnvrt}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ContentStringFormat="#.##" ></Label>
```

Comment: we can directly add converters, adding through StaticResource is not the only way. Why we are using as staticresource is, we can use them at multiple places.

Comment: @WPFUser Another reason for a resource converter is, it can be placed 'inline' in a binding string without making the converter itself a `MarkupExtension`.

Answer (score 0):

The converter should be applied to the binding itself so putting it in a `Style` doesn't make much sense I am afraid.

@grek40's solution hardcodes the binding path in the `Style` which make the `Style` pretty much useless if your intention was to to create a generic `Label` style that will work for all bindings.

Forget about trying to include the converter in the `Style` and apply it to each and every binding:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <local:NanToNullConverter x:Key="NanToNullConverter" />
</Application.Resources>


<Label Style="{DynamicResource LabelStyle}" Content="{Binding Filters_TanksModelObject.RunDown_HeaderPressureDischargeStart, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
    Converter={StaticResource NanToNullConverter}}"  ContentStringFormat="#.##" />
```

The other option would be to create a custom `Label` control that handles the conversion from `Double.Nan` to `null` behind the scenes without using a converter.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <Binding Path="Content" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}">
```

Using RelativeSource in here, will take Binding as a Source and search for Path "Content" in Binding and that will end as Binding Error.
You can access the Correct path and no source, if you are sure about the type of DataContext.

or,

```
<Binding Path="Content" RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Label}}>
```

if it is inside Template,

```
 <Binding Path="Content" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}">
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but there is no sign of a `ControlTemplate`, so you are actually wrong using the `TemplatedParent` relative source.